# How to write to a file from end to start in c++

Tags: c++, text, io, binary

I have a function that computes the result I need on the fly (end result being ~50MB text files containing only chars), but in reverse order.

To illustrate:
My function will compute "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ...", but I require "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" to be written to a file.

I would like to write this to an output file, on the fly, from end to start.

Currently I'm buffering, reversing, and writing to a file with `std::ofstream::binary`, but I need to cut down the associated time and more importantly space overhead.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Edit: output size is known.

Comment: Why can't you just reverse the file after it has been written?

Comment: Have you tried a memory mapped file?

Comment: molbdnilo, is there a way to do this without any additional overhead?

Comment: John, I have looked into memory mapping, but as I understand it - memory mapping a file would reserve address space for the entire file size, right? I’d like to avoid that if possible...

Comment: @stoposto It would reserve virtual memory for the file. That doesn't mean that all that memory would be simultaneously occupying physical memory.

Comment: @john, I’m seeking consistency, and having looked into mmap, it seems there’s little I can do to force consistency - e.g. that would be fine if calls to say, madvise(...sequential etc)) were strictly followed, to force unloading of pages once accessed, but I believe they aren’t...unless they can be made to? and thank you :)

Comment: Fill a stack or linked-list (using forward chaining) and then write the stack or list nodes to the file.

Comment: It would be infinitely more efficient to compute the results in the target order. Writing a file in reverse is horrifically inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, writing files from end to start is inefficient solution, because you loose some time on file pre-allocation and seeking. Better just to write array from end to start to file.

I don't know exactly how is written your program, so my answer could be not so accurate as you want, but I assume it could be done something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>


// Variant 1
void writeMyData(const std::vector<int>& data, std::ofstream& stream)
{
    for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); it++)
        stream.write((const char*)&*it, sizeof(int));
}


// Variant 2
void writeMyData2(const int* data, int length, std::ofstream& stream)
{
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        stream.write((const char*)(data + i), sizeof(int));
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> yourBuffer = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open ("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
    
    // Write: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    // Variant 1
    writeMyData(yourBuffer, file);
    
    // Variant 2
    //writeMyData2(yourBuffer.data(), yourBuffer.size(), file); 
    
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

So, you can use reverse iterators (`rbegin`, `rend` instead of `begin`, `end`) or just iterate loop in reverse order.

**Update:**
Or you can reverse your data in RAM inplace, and then just write all data at once. Probably, it will be the most efficient way.

```
std::reverse(std::begin(yourBuffer), std::end(yourBuffer));
stream.write((const char*)yourBuffer.data(), sizeof(int) * yourBuffer.size());
```

Be attentive with `sizeof(int)` - probably you have `char` or some another type.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you requirements like this:

- Write data in binary form (although you are talking about text files somehwere)
- You want to store plain chars
- You know the number of characters to write in advance
- And then write the the first element at the end, then one before and so on.

If you realy do not want to use buffers, then you must use `seekp`. But already now some hint: This will be a very slow solution.

Anyway, how to do? So:

- First open a file for output and check, if it could be opened
- Calculate the offset position of the last charachter in the output file
- Seek to this position and write
- Decrement offset

Seek and write will look like this

```
fileStream.seekp(offset--).put(testData[index]);
```

Since I do not have your calculation function, I created some dummy data. This needs to be adapted by you.

See the following example snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

// The known size of test data
constexpr size_t OutputSize = 50'000U;
// Some simple test data
static std::array<char, OutputSize> testData{};

int main() {

    // You will calculate the data in a different part of your code
    // I jsut fill the array with some data
    std::iota(testData.begin(), testData.end(), 0);

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened.
    if (std::ofstream fileStream{ "r:\\test.bin", std::ofstream::binary }; fileStream) {

        // Caculate position offset of last element
        size_t offset{ (OutputSize - 1)};

        // Calculate and write data
        for (size_t index{}; index < OutputSize; ++index) {

            // Your claculation here
            // . . .

            // Seek and write data
            fileStream.seekp(offset--).put(testData[index]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again. Seeking is very slow.